# FPM vs CLI with threads in symfony project. How to manage classes?

Tags: php, symfony, command-line, pthreads, autoload

I have a symfony project and some symfony services(symfony commands) that needs pthread extension. All classes that need pthread are packed in a bundle. This bundle has dependencies versus other bundle but not viceversa.

Because Pthread extension is not supported in fpm mode(damn!!!!).

How I can "hide" all classes that use pthread in order to have all the stuff in the same repository ? I need to use web part in fpm **WITHOUT** threads and services in cli **WITH** threads.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved adding in AppKernel

```
if (extension_loaded('pthreads')) {
   $bundles[] = new xxxxx\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxBundle();
}
```